# How can I render two variables in src attribute of razor view?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, razor

The framework I am using is .NET 6.

Previously, the `src` attribute of the image element like this:

```
<img src="@ImageServer/images/BG.png" />
```

The variable of `ImageServer` stores the URL of the image server.

Recently, I need to add a token in it for anti-theft chain.

I tried it like this:

```
<img src="@ImageServer/images/BG.png@GetToken()" />
```

However, after the program is run, the `src` turns out to be this:

```
<img src="https://www.aaa.com/images/BG.png@GetToken()" />
```

What's wrong with my code and how can I render two variables in `src` attribute? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The text just before the `@` is causing the render engine to not parse the `@` as a server-side code indicator.

Make the whole value server-side calculated, instead of outputting small pieces of server-side values into client-side values.  For example:

```
<img src="@(ImageServer + "/images/BG.png" + GetToken())" />
```

This way the view engine sees everything within the `@()` as a server-side expression and outputs the result of that expression.

Similarly, with string interpolation:

```
<img src="@($"{ImageServer}/images/BG.png{GetToken()}")" />
```

Comment: The second way works while the first way always reports missing ; error.

Comment: @MelonNG: I made a quick edit after posting the answer, my original version used `${}` syntax instead of `@()`, which was incorrect.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works now. However, I have to modify lots of codes for this. That's so troublesome for .net core